# HOW-TO: git show hexsha:directorypath/file

Tags: python, git, gitpython

Thank you for supporting this awesome module (GitPython) that I have been working with the last couple of weeks.

I tried to find in the documentation the equivalent in GitPython of how to make the call to "git show"

```
git show <hexsha>:<directory>/<file>
```

even with interacting with git directly

```
git_ = irepo.git
```

Could you please enlighten me on how to manage and make the above "git show" call given that hexsha,directory,file are known ?

Comment: You're probably looking for `git show <sha> -- <path>`.

Comment: thanks Jubobs. the post was targeting the GitPython module in Python, and not the Git command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As GitPython doesn't wrap the `show` subcommand, one will indeed have to use the git command wrapper directly.

The call `git show <hexsha>:<directory>/<file>` would look like this in git-python.

```
import git
r = git.Repo(path_to_repo)
res = r.git.show("%s:%s" % (hexsha, file_path))
```

`res` will be a string containing output produced by `git show`, which you will have to parse yourself.

More information on how to use git directly can be found [in the official documentation](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly).